# How does JVM notify a thread blocked by `join()`?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, notify

The `join()` method waits for a thread to die. it use `wait` to do this.

```
if (millis == 0) {
            while (isAlive()) {
                wait(0);
            }
        }
```

So when the thread exits, how can it notify threads in wait set.

1. I try to find code in JDK source code, but failed. Can anyone show me the relevant code snippets?
2. when a thread in wait set, it may check `isAlive()` so many times for its timeslice, is this a waste?
3. if `isAlive()` is false, it just return, that thread is already in wait set. Is the `while(isAlive())` necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. I try to find code in JDK source code, but failed. Can anyone show me the relevant code snippets?

The pathname for the `Thread` class in the OpenJDK jdk8u source tree is `jdk/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java`.  The code for `join()` is below.

The native code where the `notifyAll` occurs is in `Thread::exit` in `hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp`.

For other releases the paths may be different.  (The `find` command is your friend.)

> 2. When a thread in wait set, it may check `isAlive()` so many times for its timeslice, is this a waste?

That is incorrect.

- The "wait set" argument is incorrect.  If the current thread  can call `isAlive()` it is not in *any* wait set.  It will only be in the "wait set" for the target `Thread` when it is in a `wait(...)` call.  It is removed from the "wait set" when the current thread is notified.

  To reiterate, a thread `t1` is in the "wait set" of another thread `t2` when `t1` is executing `t2.wait(...)`.
- A `wait(0)` call means "wait **until notified** without a timeout".  (It does NOT mean the same thing as`sleep(0)` or `yield()`!)  Therefore, this is not a busy loop.
- The loop will *usually* go around zero or one time only.  (But see the next part of my answer.)

> 3. If isAlive() is false, it just return, that thread is already in wait set. Is the while(isAlive()) necessary?

- Your "wait set" logic is incorrect (as above).
- The loop is necessary.  It is possible for any application code that has a reference to the target `Thread` object to call `Object.notify()` on that it.  That causes the `wait(0)` to return.  But since this "wake up" is spurious, it is necessary to check that the target `Thread` has actually ended (by calling `isAlive()`) and maybe waiting again.

  This *could* happen repeatedly ... if application code is doing something silly ... but it shouldn't.

---

```
public final synchronized void join(long millis)
throws InterruptedException {
    long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long now = 0;

    if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (millis == 0) {
        while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }
    } else {
        while (isAlive()) {
            long delay = millis - now;
            if (delay <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            wait(delay);
            now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the implementation of `Thread` is in native code.  That is where the `notifyAll` that wakes up the joining threads is made.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

> 1. wait() is a native method and uses System code. There is no Java code for that.
> 2. wait() is not a means to wait for a Thread but to synchronize on a certain object. Wait() is the wrong method to pause a thread, you need to use sleep().
> 3. The counterpart of wait() is notify() or notifyAll(). This will wake up Threads which wait for the calling object. Wait() and notify are part of the Object.class and need a synchronization on the object.

A Thread is alive as long as its run method is executing. If you join a thread the calling thread will automatically halt.
If you want to let a thread wait then use Thread.sleep.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(){
  public void run(){
     try {
        sleep(5000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
     System.out.println("I'm done");
  }
}

t1.start();
//The calling thread will wait here for 5 sec.
t1.join();
```